# Apache Camel not working with Groovy

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

My original issue is that I want to use `System.currentTimeMillis()` as fileName.
**Try1**

```
{date:now:SimpleDateFormat}
```

does not support it. I can print Milliseconds with `S` but its difference from the previous second.

**Try2**
Tried using inline groovy dsl but got error. I think this was a wrong approach but I love to have inline Scripting language support in Camel

```
<to uri="file://D:/Projects/?fileName=TestPipeline_$groovy{new Date()}.txt"/>
```

**Try 3**
Now I have lowered my expectation and thought to use groove straight forward. As a first pass tried Sping DSL [example](http://camel.apache.org/groovy.html)
by just writing

```
<groovy>new Date()</groovy>
```

But application context doesn't recognize `groovy` tag.

```
Invalid content was found starting with element 'groovy'. One of
```

I am using Camel 2.9.2 and included camel-groovy-2.9.2.jar in lib folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the error on your 3rd try because `<groovy>` is only allowed in `<translate>` `<setBody>` or `<setHeader>` (there might be other options).

I'd try something like:

**edited**

```
<setHeader headerName="nowInMillis">
    <groovy>new Date().getTime()</groovy>
</setHeader>
<log message="/////////////// ${in.header.nowInMillis}" loggingLevel="INFO"/>
<to uri="file://D:/Projects/?fileName=TestPipeline_${in.header.nowInMillis}.txt"/>
```

Hope this helps,
Gergely

Comment: Thanks. I didn't get any error but not getting time in millisecond. fileName=Test_${in.header.nowInMillis}.txt returned Test_.txt file.

Comment: new script looks perfectly fine to me. But somehow I am still getting TestPipelline_.txt. There is no error on console though.

Comment: log message is empty too! Iy just say `INFO  route8                         - /////////////// `